# Programmatically refresh SAML token for Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, login, adfs

Am using Map Network Drive in Windows Explorer to add a Sharepoint folder. This link is valid for the lifetime of the security token that Sharepoint returns (say 10 hours). When the token expires, the only way to access the mapped drive is by re-logging on to Sharepoint online from the browser.

Is it possible to programmatically refresh the token pre or post expiration using cached credentials that avoids this re-logon step, say through a console app that can be run manually or scheduled? I have come across several samples that login to SPO by supplying a username and password, but this won't work in my case because SPO is configured to use windows authentication via ADFS. I have also come across samples that modify the global.asax to refresh the token, but not sure if this will work in my case either, because the SP installation is in the cloud and I don't know if I can modify global.asax in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this thread: [Mounted Office 365 sharepoint workspaces lose connectivity - how to fix?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31877/mounted-office-365-sharepoint-workspaces-lose-connectivity-how-to-fix/32098#32098)

I proposed an answer using PowerShell but the original poster has not had a chance to implement it. Basically it is a PowerShell script that logs into the site and then accesses a web page. Please let me know if this works I am very curious about this.

Here is some code adapted for your case:

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://portal.domain.com/");

$request.set_PreAuthenticate($true);
$credCache = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials;
$request.Credentials = $credCache;

$response = $request.GetResponse();
$requestStream = $response.GetResponseStream();
$readStream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $requestStream
$data = $readStream.ReadToEnd()
$data
$readStream.Close()
$response.Close()
```

Comment: Any idea what proxy server is giving the 407 error? Is it same to assume it is on your network?

Comment: Robert, I tried using your code and ran into:  
"(407) Proxy Authentication Required."
I then added the following lines:  
`    $request.Proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest].DefaultWebProxy;  
    request.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials;`    
but got:  
"Property 'Credentials' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable. "  
I then converted the script to a C# program.  
Now, I get a Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: Yes, it is a proxy on our intranet.

Comment: The 'Credentials' error was a goof-up on my part. This code now also produces the 403 error: `$request.Proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy;
$request.Proxy.Credentials = $credCache;
`

Comment: Found this link which fixed the 403 error: http://razirais.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/how-to-fix-sharepoint-online-403-forbidden-error-while-downloading-files-using-client-object-model/  but now getting back a page with message "Microsoft Online Services requires JavaScript to sign in. This web browser either does not support JavaScript, or scripts are being b
locked."

Comment: That is likely a valid page. Did this refresh the SAML token at all? You might want to point it to a small document like a dummy text file.

Comment: I don't know if it refreshed the SAML token. I signed out of SPO, and I am still able to open documents from the mounted drive. I guess I'll have to wait till the token expires, although I would have thought that signing out would have expired the token.

Comment: I ran the script after the token expired but it didn't refresh the token.

Comment: I think we have two possible choices on where to go next. 1. A script that unmounts and remounts the drive on a schedule or 2. a script that downloads a file from the mounted drive on a schedule (a small text file, for example). If you would like, I could write those for you. If so, I'll propose them as a second answer.

Comment: #1 would be useful. Isn't #2 the same as the script you already provided?

Comment: Nope, the idea would be to download it from the mapped drive  letter rather than the URL directly. I'll work on both for you.

Comment: I'm now following this thread!